# Twilio magic number that can receive an SMS from an alphanumeric sender ID

Tags: twilio

The magic numbers on this guide seem to only work when paired with long numbers:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials#test-sms-messages

Do they have a magic number that can receive a message from an alphanumeric sender ID? I'm based in a country where pre-registration is required.

Comment: The link you provided can be used for test scenarios but no SMS will be sent. From you question, I assume you actually want to receive messages. Or do you want to send SMS from alphanum senders?

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I was looking for a way to receive a successful response in a test scenario. I ended up sending an actual message to a recipient where dynamic alphasender IDs are allowed.